# Can't post an answer on AskDifferent -- "This looks like spam."

Tags: support, spam, filtering

I'm seeing my perfectly reasonable answer marked as spam. I get the error: "This looks like spam." Any ideas on how I can get my answer published?

The question is: [Will my Bluetooth earbuds work with my Apple Watch even if I don't have my phone with me?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198308/will-my-bluetooth-earbuds-work-with-my-apple-watch-even-if-i-dont-have-my-phone)

My answer is:

---

> You can listen to music without your iPhone. Each of these sections
>   explain how to do that.
>
> ### Make a music playlist
>
> You can keep one music playlist on your Apple Watch at a time.
>   Audiobooks and podcasts aren't compatible.
>
> 1. On your iPhone, go to the Music app.
> 2. Tap My Music > Playlists > New.
> 3. Give your playlist a name, and then tap Add Songs.
> 4. Search or tap to find songs, artists, or albums to add.
> 5. When you find something that you'd like to add, tap "+".
> 6. After you add the item, tap Done. You can then search for more music to add.
> 7. When you're done adding music, tap Done to save your playlist. **(A)**
>
> ### Sync your playlist
>
> 1. Set your Apple Watch on its charger and make sure the device is charging.
> 2. On your iPhone, go to Settings > Bluetooth. Make sure Bluetooth is turned on.
> 3. From the Apple Watch app on your iPhone, tap My Watch > Music > Synced Playlist.
> 4. Tap the playlist you want to sync to your Apple Watch. When a message next to your playlist says Sync Pending, your playlist will
>      begin syncing from your iPhone to your Apple Watch.
> 5. Wait until the sync is finished before using your Apple Watch. To see the sync progress, open the Apple Watch app on your iPhone and tap
>      Music. You might need to download any music stored in the cloud, such
>      as music from Apple Music or iTunes Match, to your iPhone before you
>      can sync it with the Watch. **(B)**
>
> [image: iphone sync playlist]
>
> ### Pair Bluetooth headphones with your Apple Watch
>
> To listen to music on your Apple Watch, you'll need to connect to
>   Bluetooth headphones:
>
> 1. Put your Bluetooth headphones in pairing mode using the instructions that came with them. You might need to enter a passkey or
>      PIN (Personal Identification Number).
> 2. On your Apple Watch, go to Settings > Bluetooth. Your Apple Watch will search for nearby Bluetooth devices.
> 3. Choose your Bluetooth headphones and enter a passkey or PIN if asked.
>
> ### Listen to the playlist on your Apple Watch
>
> After pairing your headphones, you can listen to your synced playlist
>   without an iPhone:
>
> 1. From the Home screen on your Apple Watch, tap the music app.
> 2. Force Press, then tap Source > Apple Watch.
> 3. Tap play to listen to your playlist.
>
> [image: watch playlist force touch]

Comment: Blame clever spammers who disguise their intention by posting some convoluted instructions enumerated 1...2..3..4..  followed by a link to their product offering the "easy way".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have enough reputation on Ask Different <strike>to submit any edits that contains that many images</strike> for the spam-filter to be sure you and your images are OK. I thought at first it was the [New User Restrictions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user):

> New users cannot:
>
> - post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile

<strike>**Solution 1**: Rework the answer slightly to not require more than two links. (You can always improve it with more images after you have some reputation.)</strike>

… but actually you only have two images there, not four. There is probably some combination of number of links, having only 1 reputation, formatting, and keyword matching (I would not be surprised if “Apple Watch” in particular is on spam watch lists right now) that are triggering a false positive in the anti-spam filter's heuristics.

The spam filters are *useful* but not very *smart*. That's usually OK, because a real user will quickly transcend whatever's making the filters unhappy, usually just by getting a bit more reputation, and it's nice to avoid just that much more spam. So…

**Solution 2**: Look for something else you can answer helpfully first, get a few upvotes, and then post your Bluetooth headphones answer.

Comment: If this is the case... that error message isn't too helpful.

Comment: @hichris123 It's true. I can only hypothesise that it's intentional though — there's no desire to immediately help real spammers to adjust their post to get through the automatic block. And since it won't often affect real users (and when it does it won't affect them for long at all), it may be considered a necessary evil. A dev would have to weigh in to be sure, but that's my educated guess as to why it's unhelpful.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Actually it is not because of the images. There are only two images there. I did see the "post more than two hyperlinks at a time" error first. I then combined the images in Photoshop so that I would only be posting two. The spam error is different.

Comment: @BenMorrow Oh, so they are! That's clever. In that case, I really don't know what's triggering the spam filter. However, increasing reputation will almost certainly impact its heuristics, so that's worth doing anyway.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Now that my rep is 25, I was able to post the answer without triggering the spam filter. Thanks for your suggestion in **Solution 2**.