# Why is my answer detected as spam?

Tags: discussion, spam, specific-answer

I provided [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128024/how-can-i-make-text-based-combat-more-engaging/128112#128112) on Gamedev and it doesn't allow me to post the answer since it thinks it's a spam.

(I am posting a link to the answer via [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UUzxrw6B) since it's detected as spam even in this question.)

What is detected as spam in this answer? I put quite an effort into writing it.

Comment: It's irrelevant, I added the mark-up on this question to quote my answer, it didn't work though, so I copied it to pastebin like so.

Comment: This belongs on meta.gamedev not here.

Comment: @Ramhound I believe that the question applies to all long answers on the various stack exchange sites, and is relevant globally, therefore it's better off being here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't post an answer on AskDifferent -- "This looks like spam."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266510/cant-post-an-answer-on-askdifferent-this-looks-like-spam)

Answer (score 1):

The answer appeared to be way too long, I split it into an answer and a comment and that solved the problem.

Comment: I don't see how that was the solution. there is a max character limit anyway plus i have seen very long answers on Anime and Manga which plenty of links about as long or even longer than what you showed in Pastebin and the Association Bonus should have bypassed any New User restrictions. possibly during your "split" you removed the real cause of detection from your answer

Comment: You can try posting the answer from the original post yourself here or as a question for yourself (you don't even need to click the post button if I remember correctly). Furthermore, What are you exactly trying to say by that? that I added spam to the answer that took me time for writing and polishing just for no reason?

Comment: no, what i'm saying is that making your answer smaller (comparing the one you posted to the one in your pastebin link) can't have been *the* fix because i've seen longer answers with more links as such length should have nothing to do with it (ie a couple of my [own](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/35576/1587) [answers](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/18882/1587) and [these](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4541/1587) [two](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/842/1587) ), rather the smaller answer no longer has the content that was triggering the block.

Comment: it's like in the Nintendo Club you can't make a post with the word *"God"* in it. making a long post with the word God in it then being able to post it when you make it much smaller but now the word God is no longer there, at first it looks like you couldn't post because it was too big but the real cause was because of the word God that you removed